# Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'accounts_profile_view' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

As you can see by the tittle I have a weird Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'accounts_profile_view' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

The weirdest thing is when using shell_plus in django, importing a user profile, then importing the reverse function from django.urlcore.resolvers I do this:

```
reverse('accounts_profile_views', args=[username])
```

and it works just fine!

I created a bunch of gist for you guys to help me out review them, here they are.

This is the model 
https://gist.github.com/140127f6303660baf8d9

This is my views file
https://gist.github.com/1a3b9651eef3fb9d22db

This is my model urls
https://gist.github.com/66fe6b1f068739f940db

and this is the whole project url 
https://gist.github.com/edea781b1efca341230b

and of course the error
https://gist.github.com/8b84bd0394d4b047dce8

Thanks for your help community!

====== UPDATE ======

I found something out, theres something weird happening on the contact_us view and template, when I go to the contact-us page the request.user.username on the header shows an empty var.

Heres my contact_us url which is part of the main views for the project:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import * 
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('apps.maincoke.views',
    url(r'^(?i)$', 'home', name='home'),
    url(r'^(?i)faqs/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'maincoke/faqs.html'}, name="main_faqs"),
    url(r'^(?i)contact-us/$','contact_us', name='contact_us'),
)
```

This is the contact_us view:

```
@login_required
@render_to("maincoke/contact_us.html")
def contact_us(request):
    mail_status = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact_us_form = ContactUsForm(request, request.POST)
        if contact_us_form.is_valid():
            mail_status = contact_us_form.send_as_mail()
            if mail_status:
                 contact_us_form = ContactUsForm(request)
    else:
        contact_us_form = ContactUsForm(request)
    return { 'contact_us_form' : contact_us_form, 'mail_status' : mail_status }
```

and this is the form, Im using django-uni-form

```
class ContactUsForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Nombre', max_length=120, required=True)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(label='Mensaje', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':'40'}), 
    required=True)

    MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 2000
    # uniForm Helper
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_id = "contact_us_form"
    layout = Layout(
        Fieldset('',
            'name', 'email', 'message'
        )
    )
    helper.add_layout(layout)

    # Submit button(s)
    submit = Submit('submit','Enviar')
    helper.add_input(submit)


    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'message']

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kw):
        super(ContactUsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.request = request

    def clean_message(self):
        message_data = self.cleaned_data['message']
        if len(message_data) > self.MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Mensaje demasiado largo")

    def send_as_mail(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        send_status=True
        mail_content_html = render_to_string('mails/contactmail.html', {'data':data})
        mail_content_text = strip_tags(mail_content_html)
        mail = EmailMultiAlternatives("Mensaje enviado de %s" % data['name'], 
                                 mail_content_text, 
                                 settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, 
                                 settings.CONTACT_MAIL_RECIPIENT
                                )
        mail.attach_alternative(mail_content_html, "text/html")
        try:
             mail.send(fail_silently=False)
        except:
             send_status=False

        return send_status
```

The information of the template is not getting rendered at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is showing you what's wrong: the `username` argument is evaluating to an empty string. You'll need to work out why this is.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('apps.accounts.views',
url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'profile_view', {}, name="accounts_profile_view"),
url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/edit/$', 'profile_edit', {}, name="accounts_profile_edit"),
)
```

It happens when the data represented here: `r'^(?P username \w+)` does not match with the given data in the reverse def: reverse('accounts_profile_views', args=[username])

```
\w  Match a word character (alphanumeric plus "_")
```

Debug the view and see whats in this username, if this contains a space, or dot, or empty string as our PyMASTER @Daniel Roseman says... this wont match and will raise this exception.